# If matrix2.getElement(int y, int x) is called what do I type in the getElement method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, get

For this assignment we are writing an immutable class that implements a matrix interface which has some matrix functions, add, subtract multiply...  We clone the data supplied to make a new matrix which is immutable.  There is a getElement(int y, int x) method in the interface which returns an int.  I can not figure out how to extract the element when all that is supplied is the indexes.  I understand the method is called on a matrix object so that is the matrix we are pulling from what I need the key word that goes in the getElement method.

```
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] data2 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        Practice m1 = new Practice(data2);

        m1.getElement(0, 1);

    }

    public Practice(int[][] matrix){
        cloneMatrix(matrix);
    }

    public static int[][] cloneMatrix(int[][] data) {

         int[][] newMatrix = new int[data.length][data[0].length];
         for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             System.arraycopy(data[i], 0, newMatrix[i], 0, data[i].length);
         }
         return newMatrix;
    }

    public int getElement(int y, int x) {

        int !!!WHAT GOES HERE!!! [y][x];
        return j;
    }

}
```

Comment: Either you have an int[][] field in the Practice class, or you pass the matrix to the method. You can't get it out of nowhere :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a bit your code to make it work :)

```java
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] data2 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        Practice m1 = new Practice(data2);

        m1.getElement(0, 1);
    }

    public int[][] myMatrix; // Changed this line

    public Practice(int[][] matrix) {
        this.myMatrix = cloneMatrix(matrix); // Changed this line
    }

    public static int[][] cloneMatrix(int[][] data) {
        int[][] newMatrix = new int[data.length][data[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(data[i], 0, newMatrix[i], 0, data[i].length);
        }
        return newMatrix;
    }

    public int getElement(int y, int x) {
        return this.myMatrix[y][x]; // Changed this line
    }
}
```

Comment: OH!!!! "this" was not working because I didn't have a "this"... the class variables was missing!  Thank you so much